# hide/show section based on screen width

Tags: jquery, angularjs, responsive-design

I'm designing a responsive website and i want to hide/show section based on screen width i don't like the media queries approach because i want the browser to load only the needed sections, for example i have a big galerie with a lot of pictures in the desktop version so i don't want the browser to load this section at all in the mobile version i tried the jquery - ajax .load() method and i found also some angularjs approaches,

i'm asking what is the better way, thank you all guys

Comment: Not sure if there are plugins to handle this. What I can think of at the moment is I'll place a div to hold all the pictures, but I'll load this pictures using Ajax on document ready. Also now I'll use media query to make this div hidden if screen size is small. Now I put a condition in my Jquery saying If div is hidden don't get the pictures

Comment: that's a really good idea, what i tried is to create an empty div with an id and based on a screen size test condition load a seperate php file like this :

(function($) { 
   if (screen.width > 992) {
       $( '#slider' ).load( 'dasktop-slider.php' );
   }
   else{
       $( '#slider' ).load( 'mobile-slider.php' );
   }
})(jQuery);

Comment: and i noticed there is other methods to manipulate the DOM in angular.js and react.js

Comment: oh good you tried similar approach, hmmm I am not into angular yet so I don't think I will be helpful in those

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-if with any of these http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Comment: you think that's better then .load() ? Thank you

Comment: It depends on what you want the result to be.  ng-if will prevent the actual html element from showing at all.  Preventing the load () will simply prevent the data from populating the element...but the element will still show...which may be all you are asking...

Comment: i have a straight forward requirement which is to have a better experience on mobile devices and rich experience on desktop

and all i want is to make sure the browser download only the nedeed elements i read this [Article](https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/) which shows how browsers interact in a different tests to determine whether or not the image was requested

Comment: in the Recommendations section the author said : "If you’re going to hide a content image, you’re not going to be able to do it by setting display:none. I recommend using a Javascript or server-side based approach instead."

and i'm looking for a better way, 
Thank you again for your time i really appreciate it

Comment: Because it kinda depends on how the images are being loaded...Can you post a sample of the HTML and JS?

Comment: So you aren't using angular at this point?  If not, then I wouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: no i haven't any angularjs in fact i have no experience with it just some knowledge